# OCommandSQLParsingException for valid json

Tags: orientdb

I'm getting an OCommandSQLParsingException:
Error on parsing command at position #0: Invalid keyword: "TYPE":"PERSON"

on

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument(json);
```

The json string is:

```
{"Salary":1500.0,"Type":"Person","Address":[{"Zip":"JX2 MSX","Type":"Home","Street1":"13 Marge Street","Country":"Holland","Id":"Address-28813211","City":"Amsterdam","From":"1996-02-01","To":"1998-01-01"},{"Zip":"90210","Type":"Work","Street1":"100 Hollywood Drive","Country":"USA","Id":"Address-11595040","City":"Los Angeles","From":"2009-09-01"}],"Id":"Person-7464251","Name":"Stan"}
```

I have tried with both 2.1-rc1 and 2.0.7 Community Edition releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to create a ODocument from JSON is using .fromJSON() API:

```
public void testOtherJson(){
  new ODocument().fromJSON("{\"Salary\":1500.0,\"Type\":\"Person\",\"Address\":[{\"Zip\":\"JX2 MSX\",\"Type\":\"Home\",\"Street1\":\"13 Marge Street\",\"Country\":\"Holland\",\"Id\":\"Address-28813211\",\"City\":\"Amsterdam\",\"From\":\"1996-02-01\",\"To\":\"1998-01-01\"},{\"Zip\":\"90210\",\"Type\":\"Work\",\"Street1\":\"100 Hollywood Drive\",\"Country\":\"USA\",\"Id\":\"Address-11595040\",\"City\":\"Los Angeles\",\"From\":\"2009-09-01\"}],\"Id\":\"Person-7464251\",\"Name\":\"Stan\"}");
}
```

Comment: When I search the OrientDB online documents I get zero results for "fromJSON". There only seems to be "toJSON". Where can I find usage info for "fromJSON".

BTW congrats on your years of effort building OrientDB!

Comment: Thanks Rick. You're right that method is not documented at all, only in JavaDoc. However the usage is simple: pass a string containing a JSON